# Menu drop down on click on one of the menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to make a drop down menu with js function, on click on one of the menu items. I have tried to achieve this with the function below but it is not working. Could you tell me where is my mistake? I want to use pure javascript and I am using SASS if it changes something.

Here is the code:

```js
let home = document.getElementById('home');
let underhome = document.querySelector('under-home');

home.addEventListener('click', function() {
  underhome.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.navbar .slider .hammburger-links {
  padding: 0 1.250em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links a {
  padding: 0 1.500em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #a6adb4;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .under-home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F6F8F9;
  min-width: 12.5em;
  min-height: 12.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .under-home a {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .open {
  display: inline;
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="hammburger-links">
      <a href="" id="home">HOME</a>
      <div class="under-home">
        <a href="">WORLD NEWS</a>
        <a href="">TRAVEL</a>
        <a href="">TECHNOLOGY</a>
        <a href="">CITY</a>
        <a href="">CULTURE</a>
        <a href="">MORE...</a>
      </div>
      <a href="">DISCOVERY</a>
      <a href="">PHOTOS</a>
      <a href="">CONTACT</a>
      <img src="images/navbar-img.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If what you are trying to achieve is a dropdown list with an `onchange` event, this is the wrong way to go about it

Comment: There is no element that the selector `under-home` would match.

Comment: what is the right way than ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few changes - the main are explained below:

- first of all added the `navbar` wrapper missing in your snippet and your `.querySelector('under-home')` was missing the `.` (class selector),
- added `position: relative` to `.hammburger-links` so that the sub-menu is positioned absolutely relative to this element,
- added `e.preventDefault()` in your *eventListener* so that the *default action* on clicking a *hyperlink* is disabled (we want the menu toggle here right),
- on `.open` use `display: flex` instead of `display: inline`,

See demo below:

```js
let home = document.getElementById('home');
let underhome = document.querySelector('.under-home');

home.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); /* prevent default hyperlink action */
  underhome.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.navbar .slider .hammburger-links {
  padding: 0 1.250em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative; /* added */
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links a {
  padding: 0 1.500em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #a6adb4;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .under-home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em; /* adjusted */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F6F8F9;
  min-width: 12.5em;
  min-height: 12.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .under-home a {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .open {
  display: flex; /* changed */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="hammburger-links">
      <a href="" id="home">HOME</a>
      <div class="under-home">
        <a href="">WORLD NEWS</a>
        <a href="">TRAVEL</a>
        <a href="">TECHNOLOGY</a>
        <a href="">CITY</a>
        <a href="">CULTURE</a>
        <a href="">MORE...</a>
      </div>
      <a href="">DISCOVERY</a>
      <a href="">PHOTOS</a>
      <a href="">CONTACT</a>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.it/200" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let home = document.getElementById('home');

home.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var element =  document.getElementById('under_home');
   element.classList.toggle("open");

});
```

```css
.navbar .slider .hammburger-links {
  padding: 0 1.250em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links a {
  padding: 0 1.500em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #a6adb4;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .under-home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  background: #F6F8F9;
  min-width: 12.5em;
  min-height: 12.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .under-home a {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.navbar .slider .hammburger-links .open {
  display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<div class="slider">
            <div class="hammburger-links">
                <a href="" id="home">HOME</a>
                <div class="under-home" id="under_home">
                    <a href="">WORLD NEWS</a>
                    <a href="">TRAVEL</a>
                    <a href="">TECHNOLOGY</a>
                    <a href="">CITY</a>
                    <a href="">CULTURE</a>
                    <a href="">MORE...</a>
                </div>
                <a href="">DISCOVERY</a>
                <a href="">PHOTOS</a>
                <a href="">CONTACT</a>
                <img src="images/navbar-img.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```